# Configure Django/Celery to send tasks to different broker

Tags: python, django, rabbitmq, celery

The system is running a Django server (1.11.5) with Celery (4.0.0) and RabbitMQ as broker.

It is necessary to send some tasks to a remote server to be processed there. This new server will have its own RabbitMQ installed to use it as broker. The problem comes when on the server where Django is running we need to select which of the tasks keep running on the local machine and which are sent to the new server.

Due to some architecture reasons is not possible to solve this using queues, tasks must be sent to the new broker.

Is it possible to create two different Celery apps in Django (each one pointing to a different broker) which their own tasks each one? How can it be done?

Comment: Do you really need two RabbitMQ instances ? You can have celery workers on different servers, all talking to the same RabbitMQ instance, so you could just ditch the existing one and send everything to the new one...

Comment: We wanted to avoid that solution because implies bigger changes than the desired. After trying the solution proposed by [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/55001994/10883175) (which implies a lot of changes too), we decided to change the way we organize Celery and RabbitMQ and use just one RabbitMQ instance with different queues.

Answer (score 0):

You can create two celery app and rename celery.py to celery_app.py to avoid auto import.

```
from celery import Celery

app1 = Celery('hello', broker='amqp://guest@localhost//')

@app1.task
def hello1():
    return 'hello world from local'
```

and

```
from celery import Celery

app2 = Celery('hello', broker='amqp://guest@remote//')

@app2.task
def hello2():
    return 'hello world from remote'
```

and for shared task:

```
from celery import shared_task


@shared_task
def add(x, y):
    return x + y
```

When you run your celery worker node:

```
celery --app=PACKAGE.celery_app:app worker
```

Comment: Even if I use @app1.task() the app.autodiscover_tasks() gets them all in both apps, I wolud like to avoid to have to add each task using the "include" parameter in app()

Comment: you can avoid autodiscover.